# How to create an interactive (clickable) animation for responsive website?

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, css-animations, paperjs

Anyone have suggestions for object animations that can show text on hover or click? 
Looking for something like this on:

Trying to make these crystals into objects to be interactive.
**[Sample mockup website here.](http://a.parsons.edu/~jung235/Tweb3/)**

Comment: http://codepen.io/sdras/pen/jEjRwo

Answer (score 0):

Surround your animations with a div, then bind to jquery mouseover and mouseout events to add and remove a css class that contains the desired text. Like this:

html:

```
<div class="crystalDiv">
  <!-- This contains an image of a crystal. You can have as many as you want -->
</div>
```

css:

```
.crystalHover:after{
    content:"Whatever text";
    position: absolute;
    /* Use top, bottom, left, right to position - it will relative to the crystal div*/
}
```

javascript:

```
$('.crystalDiv').on('mouseover',function(e) {
    $(this).addClass('crystalHover');
});
$('.crystalDiv').on('mouseout',function(e) {
    $(this).removeClass('crystalHover');
});
// You can do the same thing with click event if you want
```